# Messaging (SMS) app missing from Windows 10 Mobile build 10536

Tags: sms, insider-preview, system-apps

The SMS (Messaging) app is missing on my Microsoft Lumia 535 dual-SIM with Windows 10 Mobile TP build 10536.1004 after resetting. How can I get it back?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the same thing, but you actually can just install it from the store. Just open this link in your phones browser:

[ms-windows-store:pdp?pfn=Microsoft.Messaging_8wekyb3d8bbwe](http://ms-windows-store:pdp?pfn=Microsoft.Messaging_8wekyb3d8bbwe)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. Microsoft have acknowledged it and provided a service-side fix. You'll have to hard reset your phone again to get the app back.

Source: [WinBeta](http://www.winbeta.org/news/messaging-app-no-longer-disappears-windows-10-mobile-build-10536)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/microsoft-messaging/9wzdncrfjbq6?tduid=%28d802791307603aab859f91b77a879929%29%28259740%29%282542549%29%28vb_wp%29%28%

I added the correct link as the one by Thomas doesn`t seem to work!

Answer (score 0):

The link and download only worked once I'd switched location off and set region as United States. Probably have to set storage to download apps to phone as well.